# Writing to an array class will not cout

Tags: c++, arrays, object

The code runs, but I cannot get `cout` to work.  Please help me, I am a beginner, and really struggling with getting the contents of my array to output.

`cout << myArray[0].getSquareName();` is the line that never `cout`'s.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class cSquare {
public:
    string SquareName;
    string getSquareName() const;
    void setSquareName(string);
    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, cSquare & s);
};

// set method
void cSquare::setSquareName(string squareName)
{
    squareName = SquareName;
}

//square name get method
string cSquare::getSquareName() const
{
    return SquareName;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const cSquare & s)
{
    os << s.getSquareName() << ' ';
    return os;
}

istream & operator >> (istream & is, cSquare & s)
{
    is >> s.SquareName;
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    string discard;
    int i = 0;
    const int MAX_SIZE = 26;
    ifstream monopoly("monopoly.txt", ios::in);
    if (monopoly.is_open())
    {
        cSquare myArray[MAX_SIZE];

        getline(monopoly, discard);
        string sname; //string to store what I read in from my file

        while (i < MAX_SIZE && monopoly >> sname)
        {
            myArray[i].setSquareName(sname);//stores the string read in into the array
            cout << myArray[0].getSquareName(); //it never cout's this
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think carefully about `squareName = SquareName;`. Which is which? How can the compiler decide?

Comment: What were the results when you used a debugger?  Which statement is causing the issue?

Comment: I have replaced void cSquare::setSquareName(string sname)
{
  sname = SquareName;
}

Comment: But still no luck :( unfortuantly.

Comment: When I run the debugger no errors are showing so I am assuming it is a logic error within the code somewhere that I have done.

Comment: It's running but does not display the cout statement to show what is being stored within the array.

Comment: Thankyou so much Remy.  I really appreciate you explaining that.

Comment: What Thomas meant was: Step through the code with a debugger one line at a time, and watch what is the value of every variable before and after every line. This will make it really obvious to you exactly what and where the error is. This is a _critical_ skill for every coder to learn.

Comment: You're assuming there's valid data in `sname`. I'd add a `std::cout << sname << std::endl;` inside the loop to be sure.

Comment: BTW there is no much sense in making such setters and getters and make SquareName public.

Answer (score 3):

Your `setSquareName()` method is assigning the object's `SquareName` member to the input parameter, which is wrong.  You need to do the opposite instead, eg:

```cpp
void cSquare::setSquareName(string sname)
{
    //sname = SquareName;
    SquareName = sname;
}
```

Also, this line:

```cpp
cout << myArray[0].getSquareName();
```

Should be this instead:

```cpp
cout << myArray[i];
```

With those 2 changes, the code works.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/7jMWIE)